# Monitoring Event ID 4660 and ID 4663 on Windows 2016 Datacenter

Tags: windows-event-log, eventviewer

I want to monitor the deletion of files and folders on a Windows 2016 Datacenter Server.
I'm already monitoring event ID 4663 and event ID 4659, which have the following description:

4659: "A handle to an object was requested with intent to delete"

4663: "An attempt was made to access an object"

I filter these events down to only those who have "DELETE" in their "Accesses" object.
However, there seems to be another Event ID, which seems logical to add to monitored events:

4660: "An object was deleted"

From what I've read online, the deletion of an object triggers both this event, as well as event 4663. And "this should be monitored in tandem with 4663, as this event does not provide the Object Name"

( Source: https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/kb/object-access-events/event-id-4660.html )

My question is; is there any reason for me to monitor event 4660, when I am already monitoring event 4663?
As I'm only interested in the deletion of objects, any other information on these events is discarded. On the other hand, is it possible that I might miss a deletion event if event 4660 is not monitored?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at Microsoft's documentation of this event instead of ManageEngine's which you can [find here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4660).

Summary: You can generally ignore 4660 as 4663 will always be logged when an object is deleted. However, you may also get a 4663 when an object is renamed whereas you only get event id 4660 when an object is deleted.

Downside is that event 4660 does not contain the objet name, only the handle id which you would need to correlate with a 4663 event.

Most people are fine just monitoring 4663 events.

Comment: Hi Luke, Thanks a lot for your feedback. That is exactly what I wanted to know. Have a great day!